# finding the no: fields that have appeared twice or more in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `data` with columns names `number, start, end`

I now need to select the numbers(fields of column `number`) which have appeared twice or more and then count them for how may times they have appeared.

Any simple way to do this?

Example: -number-------start-------end----

```
      191            x          x
      123            x          x
      45             x          x
      191            x          x
      37             x          x
      191            x          x
      45             x          x
```

So now the result should be : 2 (191 and 45 - both repeated twice or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `number`, COUNT(`number`) AS count
FROM `data`
GROUP BY `number`
HAVING COUNT(`number`) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(`number`) DESC;
```

For the given set of input values, the output shall be:

```
------------------
| number | count |
------------------
|   191  |   3   |
------------------
|   45   |   2   |
------------------
```

Comment: So does it give the total no: of unique no:s which have appeared twice or more?

Comment: Yes, `GROUP BY` will select unique numbers and `COUNT()` will give the number of times they appeared.

Comment: I edited the question with an example to be more clear so is it exactly the same?

Comment: @user1424394 Edited the reply. Please check.

Comment: Thanks dude. will check ri8 now and see if its coming or not...so please be present

Comment: Error dude: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING COUNT(`conference_id`) > 1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: @user1424394 Oh, just move the `HAVING` clause one line up. Edited again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13953/discussion-between-user1424394-and-nerd-herd)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT number, COUNT(1)
FROM table
GROUP BY number
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2;
```

Comment: That won't select numbers appearing twice.